# The same code for validation and throwing exceptions

Tags: php, oop, exception, throw

I have a class with a bunch of methods in it. Some of these methods start their blocks with checking or validating the arguments passed to them and throw an exception if neccessary. Unfortunately (or fortunately) these validations are often the same, so I need to write the identical code block at the beginning of each method for the validation stuff. For example it comes down to look like that:

```
<?php

class SomeClass {
    public function methodA($arg1, $arg2) {
        if (!doSomeValidation($arg1)) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid format');
        }

        // the rest of code
    }

    public function methodB($arg1) {
        if (!doSomeValidation($arg1)) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid format');
        }

        // the rest of code
    }

    public function methodC($arg1, $arg2, $arg3) {
        if (!doSomeValidation($arg1)) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid format');
        }

        if (!doAnotherValidation($arg1)) {
            throw new Exception('Not allowed');
        }

        // the rest of code
    }

}
```

As you noticed, in this example all methods contain the same code for validating stuff except for the last method which also has another checking stuff, but it does not matter at all in this case. Now, if i wanted to edit the message for these exceptions or change the way the validations are performed, I would need to do it for each block separately instead of doing it just one at a time. What is more I am not really in favour of writing wet code.

My idea was to move all the validation code and wrap it into separate private methods, so it could be called from other methods when needed:

```
class SomeClass {
    private function validateA($arg) {
        if (!doSomeValidation($arg)) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid format');
        }
    }

    private function validateB($arg) {
        if (!doAnotherValidation($arg)) {
            throw new Exception('Not allowed');
        }
    }

    public function methodA($arg1, $arg2) {
        $this->validateA($arg1);

        // the rest of code
    }

    public function methodB($arg1) {
        $this->validateA($arg1);

        // the rest of code
    }

    public function methodC($arg1, $arg2, $arg3) {
        $this->validateA($arg1);
        $this->validateB($arg3);

        // the rest of code
    }

}
```

My question: is it a right way to achieve this? Does it not mess up the stack trace if the exception is not caught? Or maybe you know a better solution to do it. Thanks.

Comment: What you're basically doing is the same as having doXXXValidation throw an exception rather than return a boolean. It won't mess with the stacktrace; the first entry will be which validation failed, the second your methodX. If you don't catch the exception, PHP will. So, it all looks okay!